# Check if facebook oauth 2.0 october 1st migration is done

Tags: facebook

I'm using facebook connect on a website, it worked well with PHP SDK 3.0.1.

Now I've downloaded and started using PHP SDK v.3.1.1 and set Encrypted Access Token to enabled. It still works without problems. Is this enough for the migration? How can I check it? I don't use the js sdk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [migration guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/), it looks like you have done all the steps you need for Facebook on an external website by upgrading to 3.1.1 PHP SDK and set encrypted access token.
If you were hosting a fan page or app inside Facebook you would also need an SSL certificate.  And there are several code changes required if you are using the javascript SDK which you say you aren't.